# boost::thread_resource_error: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: multithreading, boost

I keep getting this message,

```
[root@vps25148 samp]# ./samp03svr &
[1] 1687
[root@vps25148 samp]#
Started server on port: 7777, with maxplayers: 500 lanmode is OFF.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::thread_resource_error> >'
  what():  boost::thread_resource_error: Resource temporarily unavailable

[1]+  Aborted                 ./samp03svr
```

This usually happens when the mysql on my gameserver is starting, is there any resolution to this?

Comment: too many threads will lead to this, as might be open sockets. Check your threading design (reduce threads) or ulimit settings

Comment: I get this with ulimit settings... @sehe  
[root@vps25148 ~]# ulimit settings
-bash: ulimit: settings: invalid number